# A function is of bounded variation if and only if the errors of its best approximation by trigonometric polynomials satisfy $\sum\frac{e_n}n<\infty$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $\mathcal P_n$ be the set of trigonometric polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ and let $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ be the supremum norm. The error of the best approximation of $f$ of degree $n$ is defined as

$$e_n(f)=\inf_{p\in\mathcal P_n}\lVert f-p\rVert_\infty.$$

A theorem of Bernstein says that if

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e_n(f)}n n^\alpha<\infty$$

for $\alpha>0$ then $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder. I conjecture that this extends to the $\alpha=0$ case with the statement that $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation instead, and also that the reciprocal holds.

There's a result of Newman and Rivlin in [Approximation of monomials by lower degree polynomials](https://doi.org/10.1007/bf01835995) (the lemma starting on the bottom of the second page, p. 452) that you can use to prove that the function

$$F_k(x)=\sum_{h=0}^\infty f_k(h)\cos(hx)$$

where

$$f_k(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac 1{\log^k(x)}$$

and the exponents are composition, satisfies

$$e_n\gg\frac{1}{\log(n)\log^2(n)\dotsm \log^{k-1}(n)(\log^k(n))^2}.$$

And it *really* looks like $\sum\frac{e_n}n$ is on the verge of diverging but doesn't quite get there.

Is the conjecture true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. If $f(x)=x \sin( \frac 1x)$ near the origin, then $f$ is $1/2$ Holder continuos and $e_n(f) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ by Jackson theorem, so that the series $\sum_n \frac{e_n(f)}{n}$ converges. But is not of bounded variation, since $f' \not \in L^1$.

EDIT

Also the converse does not hold. Take $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\log x}$ for $x$ close to 0, which is continuous and increasing. If $P_n$ realizes the best approximation then
$$
|f(0)-f(\delta)| \leq |f(0)-P_n(0)|+|P_n(0)-P_n(\delta)|+|P_n(\delta)-f(\delta)| \leq 2e_n(f)+Cn \delta,$$
where $C \geq \|P_n\|_\infty$ for every $n$,  using Bernstein inequality $\|P'_n\|_\infty \leq n\|P_n\|_\infty$. Taking $\delta=n^{-2}$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2\log n} \leq 2e_n(f)+\frac Cn$$ and then $e_n(f) \geq \frac{1}{8\log n}$ for large n and the series $\sum_n \frac{e_n(f)}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you know about the other implication?

Comment: False, too. See the edit.